# Adding constraints to Generative Adversarial Networks, e.g. no dogs with two heads

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, generative-adversarial-network

In the GAN framework, it's not uncommon that the generator will violate hard constraints of the real distribution that are not explicitly represented in an image, e.g. dogs rarely have more than one head or 4 legs.

Given that there's no head or leg-counting neuron and that one is not interested in using domain knowledge to mine these specifications and use them as input to the discriminator, what are some ways to mine and enforce such specifications in the context of GANs or constraint optimization problems.

In my own case, the data consists of piano rolls, that is, one axis represents time, T, and the other represents notes, N.
Some example of specifications could be: A) For every t in T, there will be only one positive valued N, i.e. one note per time step B) A positive valued N can only exist if its count of positive valued direct and indirect neighbors in the Note axis is equal or greater than 2.

e.g.

```
Invalid 
10110110 
11001101

Valid 
00000000 
11101111
```

Advice or suggestions are very welcome!
One example of control on low-level image features.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07865.pdf

Comment: What you can do is to give the tools to your disciminator to detect those kinds of behaviors. In your case, you have "neighbour rules" so I would add conv layers over timesteps at some point in your discriminator. Just my 2cents

Comment: Two possible solutions I'm aware of are coming up with a numerical representation of what those constraints are and than either adding these constraints as input to the discriminator and/or generator or adding a regularizer to the discriminator's loss.
I'm interested in a more general solution and automatic where the constraints and loss are learned. Although I imagine more data can improve  it, there are still no guarantees that the constraints will be satisfied, e.g. two-headed dogs.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are positing that the neurons in the discriminator couldn't be able to count the number of dog heads in the input image but why would that be the case? Counting the number of features of a given kind is something the network could learn.